# Trouble migrating bot to Azure / O365

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth, office365, botframework

I used to manage bot and channel registrations via https://dev.botframework.com/bots. 
I'm running an app service on azure that is hosting my bot. This app service is under a corporate azure subscription and I login to azure with my **company O365 account** via my organizations's sign-in page.

I use this login for `eu.luis.ai`, `portal.azure.com`, `apps.dev.microsoft.com` and `dev.botframework.com`.

Since i'm trying to migrate the bots, I'm facing **several issues**:

- **The migration button**
  When pressing the migration button, I'm getting the error

  > Failed to find any Azure subscriptions for the current user.
- **From Scratch "Bot Channel Registration"**
  In the Azure portal, when I create a new Bot Channels Registration I'm able to see it on `dev.botframework.com`, but in the azure portal on the blades **Channels**, **Test in Web Chat** and **Analytics** (IFrame to `dev.botframework.com`) I get the error

  > There was an error refreshing your sign-in information. Refresh and try again.
  >   ***But:** When I open the IFrame source in a new tab, I'm able to access those pages.*
- **Where goes my app in the Application Registration Portal?**
  In the newly created "Bot Channel Registration" resource on azure, when I click the **"manage" link** for the Microsoft App Id, I get an error, that the application is not available or not assigned to my account (but I'm still logged in with the same credentials).

What I tried so far:
- I asked several collegues to try the same (they all have the same problem)
- Deleted browser cache, tried in-private sessions, tried different browsers etc., logged out & in, ...
- I also have no live account with my organizations email address
- For the migration button problem, I was able to **hack around** the problem using a chrome extension to replace authorizations headers for requests going to https://management.azure.com with the access token from the azure portal.

It looks to me to some kind of token incompatibility but I'm not sure where the problem needs to be fixed.

Any ideas or help appreciated!

see also:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Bot-Framework/bot-service-migrate-bot
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/32714965-bot-registration-unusable-after-migration#comments

Comment: The email address you use that is linked to your Azure subscription is the same email you registered the bots with on dev.botframework.com?

Comment: @JasonSowers Yes, the same email is listed under administrators. When I create a bot channel registration resource, it is going to be listed listed under dev.botframework.com too

Comment: I will escalate this for you can you please post an issue on our [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new) so we may track it better

Comment: Issue on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4058